# How to troubleshoot slow performance on URL with Rails + Mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, scalability, mongomapper

We could use advice on a scaling/ops issue.

We have a simple mobile app that runs on Rails 3.2.12 and uses MongoMapper instead of ActiveRecord. There is one database call that sporadically performs poorly, causing users to write in and complain. It isn't clear why. We can't install NewRelic because of MongoMapper, and the data returned by Mongo isn't a lot (< 200KB). There isn't much logic being executed in the controller, either.

The problem seems exacerbated with more users. The server runs on a VPS, one shared with 30 nodes. The hosting company says average I/O utilization is at 12%, well below the critical threshold.

Since we can't use NewRelic, what's the best approach for troubleshooting the problem?

Here's output from `explain`:

```
User.collection.find({:username_downcase => 'banana2006'}).explain
=> {"cursor"=>"BtreeCursor username_downcase", 
    "isMultiKey"=>false, 
    "n"=>1, 
    "nscannedObjects"=>1, 
    "nscanned"=>1, 
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans"=>1, 
    "nscannedAllPlans"=>1, 
    "scanAndOrder"=>false, 
    "indexOnly"=>false, 
    "nYields"=>0, 
    "nChunkSkips"=>0, 
    "millis"=>3, 
    "indexBounds"=>{"username_downcase"=>[["banana2006", "banana2006"]]}, 
    "allPlans"=>[{"cursor"=>"BtreeCursor username_downcase", "n"=>1, "nscannedObjects"=>1, "nscanned"=>1, "indexBounds"=>{"username_downcase"=>[["banana2006", "banana2006"]]}}], "oldPlan"=>{"cursor"=>"BtreeCursor username_downcase", "indexBounds"=>{"username_downcase"=>[["banana2006", "banana2006"]]}}, "server"=>"x.com"}
```

Output from `db.serverStatus`:

```
> db.serverStatus()
{
        "host" : "mongo.x.com",
        "version" : "2.2.0",
        "process" : "mongod",
        "pid" : 15957,
        "uptime" : 5232267,
        "uptimeMillis" : NumberLong("5232267460"),
        "uptimeEstimate" : 5178261,
        "localTime" : ISODate("2013-05-19T19:32:14.561Z"),
        "locks" : {
                "." : {
                        "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                "R" : NumberLong(131563265),
                                "W" : NumberLong("2824934127")
                        },
                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                "R" : NumberLong(536751143),
                                "W" : NumberLong(644540368)
                        }
                },
                "admin" : {
                        "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(11906),
                                "w" : NumberLong(0)
                        },
                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(424),
                                "w" : NumberLong(0)
                        }
                },
                "local" : {
                        "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(13829064),
                                "w" : NumberLong(0)
                        },
                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(96863334),
                                "w" : NumberLong(0)
                        }
                },
                "x-development" : {
                        "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(22074626),
                                "w" : NumberLong(645528)
                        },
                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(2876041),
                                "w" : NumberLong(3693)
                        }
                },
                "x-production" : {
                        "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong("39251850394"),
                                "w" : NumberLong(1466862624)
                        },
                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong("17410130690"),
                                "w" : NumberLong(858232658)
                        }
                },
                "z-development" : {
                        "timeLockedMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1897461),
                                "w" : NumberLong(0)
                        },
                        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(134836),
                                "w" : NumberLong(0)
                        }
                }
        },
        "globalLock" : {
                "totalTime" : NumberLong("5232267461000"),
                "lockTime" : NumberLong("2824934127"),
                "currentQueue" : {
                        "total" : 0,
                        "readers" : 0,
                        "writers" : 0
                },
                "activeClients" : {
                        "total" : 0,
                        "readers" : 0,
                        "writers" : 0
                }
        },
        "mem" : {
                "bits" : 64,
                "resident" : 87,
                "virtual" : 9071,
                "supported" : true,
                "mapped" : 4207,
                "mappedWithJournal" : 8414
        },
        "connections" : {
                "current" : 3,
                "available" : 9597
        },
        "extra_info" : {
                "note" : "fields vary by platform",
                "heap_usage_bytes" : 198457056,
                "page_faults" : 3176777
        },
        "indexCounters" : {
                "btree" : {
                        "accesses" : 18208995,
                        "hits" : 18208994,
                        "misses" : 0,
                        "resets" : 0,
                        "missRatio" : 0
                }
        },
        "backgroundFlushing" : {
                "flushes" : 87204,
                "total_ms" : 563603,
                "average_ms" : 6.463040686207055,
                "last_ms" : 1,
                "last_finished" : ISODate("2013-05-19T19:31:55.201Z")
        },
        "cursors" : {
                "totalOpen" : 0,
                "clientCursors_size" : 0,
                "timedOut" : 0
        },
        "network" : {
                "bytesIn" : 9286320357,
                "bytesOut" : 148669944094,
                "numRequests" : 5102457
        },
        "opcounters" : {
                "insert" : 0,
                "query" : 3213569,
                "update" : 1989197,
                "delete" : 0,
                "getmore" : 30944,
                "command" : 216139
        },
        "asserts" : {
                "regular" : 0,
                "warning" : 0,
                "msg" : 0,
                "user" : 0,
                "rollovers" : 0
        },
        "writeBacksQueued" : false,
        "dur" : {
                "commits" : 30,
                "journaledMB" : 0.04096,
                "writeToDataFilesMB" : 0.043131,
                "compression" : 0.9447148096039855,
                "commitsInWriteLock" : 0,
                "earlyCommits" : 0,
                "timeMs" : {
                        "dt" : 3069,
                        "prepLogBuffer" : 0,
                        "writeToJournal" : 0,
                        "writeToDataFiles" : 0,
                        "remapPrivateView" : 0
                }
        },
        "recordStats" : {
                "accessesNotInMemory" : 1102532,
                "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 657056,
                "admin" : {
                        "accessesNotInMemory" : 0,
                        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
                },
                "local" : {
                        "accessesNotInMemory" : 0,
                        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
                },
                "x-development" : {
                        "accessesNotInMemory" : 1555,
                        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 1304
                },
                "x-production" : {
                        "accessesNotInMemory" : 1074115,
                        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 639842
                },
                "z-development" : {
                        "accessesNotInMemory" : 0,
                        "pageFaultExceptionsThrown" : 0
                }
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Have you used `explain` on the query to see how the query is performed when executed? Is it doing lots of scanning rather than using an index for example?

Comment: Updated the question with output from explain. Thanks, @WiredPrairie.

Comment: that query took 3 milliseconds. Can you access mongod logs and see what queries are logged there - all queries that take longer than 100ms will be logged.

Comment: Thanks, @AsyaKamsky. What's the best way to do this? Should I dump the whole log file somewhere? Is there a command to only retrieve the slowest queries?

Comment: I'm talking about the log file that mongod process writes to.  It's a file on disk.  So I would use grep to look for slow queries - maybe start with grep '[0-9][0-9][0-9]ms$' logfilepathandname.

Comment: Thanks @AsyaKamsky, none of these queries appear to take longer than 100ms. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Actually there are a handful that take longer than 300ms. Here's an example: May  8 00:04:43 [conn656] getmore x-production.y query: { query: {}, $snapshot: true } cursorid:3621074530748400404 ntoreturn:0 exhaust:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 13 locks(micros) r:2036670 nreturned:1885 reslen:4194364 1553ms

Comment: If the server isn't the problem, then you should take a look on the client. Try to put this task in another thread or execute it asynchronously.

Comment: @Crashalot this query is querying for all documents in the collection and it's scanning it by _id index order (snapshot) - you need to find what is calling it - it's likely your problem. 1.5 seconds is a long time and it is scanning your entire collection.  Can you check other lines from conn656?

Comment: thanks, @AsyaKamsky. is conn656 a file somewhere, or what is it? we have one query that needs to return all 6500 documents in a collection. is this a problem? (we cache results, of course.)

Comment: I meant grepping through your log file for other things the same connection was doing (you can see [conn656] on the line in the logs you included in your previous comment).  Even if it needs all the documents, you shouldn't see it run very often if results are really cached.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, the connect doesn't appear again in the logs. how can you tell it's scanning the whole collection btw? we already provided the output from db.serverStatus(). would it help to provide other details?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky after scanning the logs, it appears the queries that scan the whole collection (we assume this is what you mean if there is an query) are related to getmore, which doesn't appear to be something we're issuing from mongomapper. does this help?

Comment: getmore is something that happens when you do a find() that's returning more than one batch worth of documents (101) the way to get more (via the driver) happens to be a getmore() call.

Comment: is the presence of getmore an indication that something is wrong with our code? i.e., would getmore not get called if our queries were structured well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up MongoDB [profiling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) although the default 100ms should be good enough.

Still, we can't tell you how to optimize Mongo queries if we don't know what they are.  What is the "one database call that sporadically performs poorly"?

In your comments you reference a long query that is using the snapshot option.  That can cause lock contention, so if you can remove the snapshot option safely you will likely see improvement.

I don't know why you say you can't use New Relic.  It might not give you automatic timing of database queries but since you know which one is the problem you can use [method tracers](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-custom-metric-collection#method_tracers) to isolate the problem and make sure it is the database rather than some other part of your code.

Comment: thanks. how do we remove the snapshot option? if it helps, we included the output from db.serverStatus().

Comment: [Snapshot](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/snapshot/) is an option applied to the query or cursor in the call made from your code.  The log says someone did something like `db.y.find( { $query: {}, $snapshot: true } ) in the `x-production` database.  You need to track down the source of they query and change it. No telling if that's the real problem though.  Tracking down mongo performance problems is hard enough when you have full access; nearly impossible on a public forum.